# pgsql how to enforce uniqueness for some keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

I have two tables. table1 has attributes unique or not

```
attribute_id     uniqueness 
   1              no
   2             yes
   3             yes
```

Table 2 has below data, there is unique constraint on combined columns object_id and attribute_id .
Now I need another unique constraint on value column for some attribute_id has uniqueness=yes.

Like, attribute_id 2 and 3 has unique=yes in table1. they can't have duplicate values in table2.

```
auto_id  object_id   attribute_id    value
  1         1           1             a
  2         2           1             a
  3         1           2             b
  4         2           2             d
```

We can't insert (attribute_id,value)=(2,b) or (2,d) and it should through  `error duplicate key value violates unique constraint` if we try to insert dup values.

I hope we can do this by trigger but it will be very slow.

Looking for better approach, any possible solution pls ?

Comment: There isn't much point in using a relational database if you aren't going to have proper tables with proper constraints and relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that with a constraint that I can think of is this:

- add the `uniqueness` column to `table2` too and fill it with the proper value
- define a `UNIQUE` constraint on `table1(attribute_id, uniqueness)`
- define a foreign key constraint on `table2`:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE table2 ADD FOREIGN KEY (attribute_id, uniqueness)
     REFERENCES table1 (attribute_id, uniqueness);
  ```
- define a partial unique index on `table2`:

  ```
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON table2 (attribute_id, value) WHERE uniqueness;
  ```

Of course this will lead to data duplication, but the foreign key will guarantee that no inconsistencies can occur.

Comment: above solution works. but have to modify partial unique index to 
`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON table2 (attribute_id, value) WHERE uniqueness is true;`

Comment: That should be exactly the same for a `boolean` column...